# How to change the size of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array [16] that has values, I want to make it `[4][4]` with the same values.

These value are not fixed, but I always will get array as this.

```
u8 pt[16] = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,
             0x08,0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,0x0d,0x0e,0x0f};
```

So, I want to change it to 4*4 array

I tried to change it, but I couldn't do it.

This is what I did, but I used 4 for loops. I want to make it less than that.

```
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < 4; j++) {
        a[i][j]= pt[j];
    }
}

for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < 4; j++) {
        a[i+1][j]= pt[j+4];
    }
}
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < 4; j++) {
        a[i+2][j]= pt[j+8];
    }
}
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < 4; j++) {
        a[i+3][j]= pt[j+12];
    }
}
```

So, can any one help me?
.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. You can obviously change the declaration from, say, `int arr[1][16];` to `int arr[4][4];` and recompile your program. How is the array declared (show us the actual line of code that declares it), and how exactly did you try to change it?

Comment: I edited.. check it out .. @KeithThompson

Comment: You haven't answered the questions I asked. How is `a` *declared* in your program (I'm looking for an actual line of C code; your `a = { ... }` is not valid C code). And you said you "tried to change it"; how did you try? Are you talking about changing the dimensions of your array object *at run time*? If so, why not just define it as a 2-dimensional array in the first place? (There may be a good reason for not doing that, but you haven't told us what it is.)

Comment: Check now @KeithThompson

Comment: So you're not *changing* the size of an array; you're *copying* the elements of a 16-element array into a 4-by-4 array. (This is why we ask for code in questions; there's no way we could have known that from your original description.) And you should also show us the declaration of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you don't change the size of array. You just change its signature.

You can access to array without `[][]`. Just get values by pointer: `*(myArray + i*16 + j)` so you can assign indexes `i`,`j` as you want.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev you almost never treat `argv` as a two dimensional array so you never use it like this... it's a one dimensional array of pointers to additional arrays; this is _very_ different. Your "add x and y" logic means if I want to get the value from the array for x=1,y=0 I will fetch the exact same memory location as for x=0,y=1... most certainly not what you intend.

Comment: @AlexanderPerechnev I think usually you would multiply `y` with width, then add `x` to that (as index inside the row `y`).

Comment: @hyde renamed it to `i`,`j` to make it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use a 1-dimensional buffer, and do the dimensions manually:

```
int width = 1;
int height = 16;

int *array = malloc(width * height * sizeof int); 

int x1 = 0; // valid values go from 0..0
int y1 = 8; // valid values go from 0..15
int value1 = array[x + y * width]; // get column x on row y

// change array dimensions
int width = 4; 
int height = 4;
array = realloc(array, width * height * sizeof int ); // no-op in this case as size does not change

int x2 = 3; // now valid values go from 0..3
int y2 = 3; // now valid values go from 0..3
int value2 = array[x + y * width]; // get column x on row y
```

Notes:

- return values of `malloc` and `realloc` should be checked (and with `realloc`, by using an extra temp variable for return value, so original value is not lost if it fails)
- above code leaves the allocated buffer uninitialized, with "random" values
- remember to `free(array)` to release allocated memory
- if you want to do a fancier transformation, where you need to move values in memory, then allocate a new buffer and copy old values to right new places, then `free` the old array, but I assume here you just want to keep the original data and just change the dimensions for accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the size of an array object that has been allocated dynamically using `malloc`. Use `realloc` function to change its size. In your case, the array would have the same size `sizeof (int [1][16]) ==  sizeof (int [4][4])` so `realloc` would not even be needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can't resize them, you can make newer bigger ones and copy the old one into it.

However in your case, if you are just wanting to treat your 1*16 as a 4*4,  you can cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to your original description, you're not *changing* the dimensions of an array, you're merely *copying* the elements of a 1-dimensional 16-element array into a 2-dimensional 4-by-4 array.

Your sequence of 4 nested `for` loops is far too complicated (apart from not working). For example, each of your outer loops:

```
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++) {
```

is fairly useless; it iterates exactly once, setting `i` to `0`.

You start with:

```
u8 pt[16] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
              0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
```

(I presume `u8` is an 8-bit unsigned type, though you don't show us its definition. It's probably better to use the standard `uint8_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>`.

And you want to copy the elements into this 2D array:

```
u8 a[4][4];
```

There are (at least) two ways to do this. You can iterate over the elements of `pt`, computing for each one which element of `a` you want to assign *to*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i ++) {
    a[i/4][i%4] = pt[i];
}
```

Or you can iterate over the elements of `a`, computing for each one which element of `pt` you want to assign *from*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j ++) {
        a[i][j] = pt[i * 4 + j];
    }
}
```

In either case, you just need a single (possibly nested) loop, not 4 separate loops.

Or you *could* just copy the entire array at once:

```
memcpy(&a, &pt, sizeof a);
```

That works because the C language makes certain guarantees about how arrays are stored in memory. The elements are stored contiguously and in the specified order, and a 2-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays (in the case of `a`, it's a 4-element array where each element is itself a 4-element array of `u8`s). It also depends on the fact that the order in which you want to copy the elements happens to match the way they're stored in memory.

(There are also some aliasing tricks you can play using pointer conversions, but I don't think I want to get into that. Such tricks are likely to work, but they can result in undefined behavior.)

A few observations on your code: It's full of [*magic numbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants), as are the snippets I've provided here. That's fine for a small example, but in the context of real-world code, magic numbers are dangerous. If I wanted to change the problem to use a 5-by-5 array, I'd have to change multiple occurrences of the number `4` to `5` *and* change `16` to `25`. It's even worse if I want to use a 4-by-5 array.

Instead, you might want to declare your arrays as:

```
#define LEN 4
uint8_t pt[LEN*LEN] = { /* ... */ };
uint8_t a[LEN][LEN];
```

and then replace all occurrences of `4` by `LEN`, and `16` by `LEN*LEN`.  Then you can change the size of the array just by changing the definition of `LEN` and recompiling.

Well, almost; you'll also have to change the initialization. Possibly you'd want to use a loop to initialize `pt`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LEN*LEN; i ++) {
    pt[i] = i;
}
```

And you should consider whether you need to do *any* of this in the first place. I don't know the context of your code, but it's quite possible that you don't need both `pt` and `a`. If declaring only one array serves your purpose, then don't waste time declaring a second array and copying into it. Of course if that's what you need you should do it -- but we can't tell from your question just what you're trying to accomplish beyond copying elements from one array to another.